# Textarea selection

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make HTML5 datepicker like control. (http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date). For this purpose I want to prevent any user selection while I'm still able to make selection through code. I prevent selection on mousedown and selectstart events, but after that I can't get the right cursor position. Can anyone give me directions or samples that do the work

Example code (with ext core framework):

```
    this.root.on('mousedown', function (evt, el) {
        me.select(el);
        evt.preventDefault();
    });

    select : function(el) {
        var cur = this.getCursorPos(el);
        var section = this.modes[this.format].getSectionByPos(cur);
        this.setTextSelection(el, section.start, section.end);
    },

    getCursorPos : function (input) {
        if ("selectionStart" in input && document.activeElement == input) {
            return {
                start: input.selectionStart,
                end: input.selectionEnd
            };
        }
        else if (input.createTextRange) {
            // code that supports other browser 
        }
        return -1;
    }

    setTextSelection : function(el, start, end) {
        if ("selectionStart" in el) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.selectionStart = start;
                el.selectionEnd = end;
            }, 1);
        }
        else if (el.createTextRange) {
            // code that supports other browser 
        }
    },
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you've tried?

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you've tried?

Comment: getCursorPos returns -1. If I remove evt.preventDefault() in mousedown it returns correct values. The problem without preventDefault is that I can't block user from overriding my section selection